# Why am I getting NULL when I run _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: s) in Flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I have this line in the code

```
dynamic response =_webViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: saveMediaJs);
```

Basically what this does is Evaluates JavaScript code into the WebView and returns the result of the evaluation.But I am getting a NULL value when I print response.What might be the reason?How to rectify this?

The code for evaluateJavascript is as follows:

```
 Future<dynamic> evaluateJavascript({@required String source}) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> args = <String, dynamic>{};
    args.putIfAbsent('source', () => source);
    var data = await _channel.invokeMethod('evaluateJavascript', args);
    if (data != null && Platform.isAndroid) data = json.decode(data);
    return data;
  }
```

So basically you are getting json.decode(data) as the output,but why is it coming as NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating JavaScript is much easier now. Take time to study this Plugin.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin/example
It will definitely solve your issue and also give your project a cleaner web View mechanism.
If you need more assistance. Reach out to me https://join.skype.com/invite/ntjGAbyMAbsN